# Safari Remote Debugging closes quickly

Tags: debugging, safari, safari-extension

Devices/Information:

- Macbook Air M1, Big Sur V11.4
- iPhone XR, iOS 14.6
- The Develop menu is enabled in Safari Technology Preview (STP) on macosx.
- Web Inspector is enabled in iOS Safari settings

I connect my iPhone to my Macbook. I open STP. I then open Safari on my iPhone. In STP, I go into the Develop Menu, select my iphone, and I see the webpage I want to inspect. I click the webpage. I see the JS console + HTML pop up, and then close 500ms later. Tried around 10 times and consistently got this behavior.

Tried:

- Resetting the trusted devices on iOS (by resetting all privacy settings).
- Connecting via the network (an option in the Develop Menu)
- Updating macosx (iOS is already updated fully)
- Both Safari and STP

What the heck do I do? I need to debug behavior in a webapp that is only existing on physical iphone devices (already tried chrome + safari iphone emulators + iOS emulator in xcode, no luck).